# Separator for custom nav menu

Tags: menus, navigation, links, footer

I creating a custom footer navigation in wordpress. I looked all over the wordpress documentation and still haven't found anything. So, what I'm trying to do is add an "|" in the navigation like this:

> Home | Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3 | Contact

I know there's a way in CSS, but I know this is generated by wordpress so I'm a little stumped on how to do this.

Comment: Are you using `wp_nav_menu`? Could you please post the code used to display the nav menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this and without using the wp_nav_menu.

Here's the code to do this and hope it might help other (Note: You need to create a menu in the admin panel to have this work).

```
            <p>
                <?php
                    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items("footer");
                        $count = count($items);
                        $i = 0;
                    foreach($items as $item):
                        $i += 1;
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $item->url; ?>"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a><?php if($i < $count){ echo "<span class='center'>|</span>";} ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`wp_nav_menu` has a `$before`and `$after` parameters which you can use to add your pipes with.

read more about [wp_nav_menu entry at the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)